# What to slice rows after fifth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey want to slice rows to alternate rows(every second row), starting at fifth row, but I want to have first five rows unsliced.

I tried with `df1 = df.iloc[5::2, :]`

but it deletes first five rows as well. Do you guys have an simple command that could work like that or I need to make two different excels and then combine them together. 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please make a small example that illustrates the input and the output that you want from it? Your question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like below, first preserve the first needed rows then do your slicing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv')
df1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:5],df.iloc[5::2, :]])
```

Comment: If I do that everything else disappears.

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: Thank you, Also I'd like to recommend you to check out documentation there are plenty one-liners out there. Cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
idx = np.arange(len(df))
df1 = df.iloc[(idx < 5) | (idx % 2 == 1)]
```

Comment: Can I ask what does np.arrange(len(df)) does?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer It creates a NumPy vector of integers from 0 to the length of `df` (`[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N]`). `(idx < 5)` makes the first five positions true and the rest false, `(idx % 2 == 1)` makes the odd positions true and the even ones false, and with `|` it "merges" the two boolean masks to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[np.r_[:5, 5:len(df):2]]
```